# Jenkins Environment Variables Conditional set

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

So I had to do a lot of different renditions of this with no success unless the environment was set before the stages. I am trying to define the environment for aws creds depending on the branch im in. qa then use qa creds for the env BUT it does not set when its inside the stage phase

```
  agent {
    docker {
      image '/terraform-npm:latest'
      registryCredentialsId 'dockerhubPW'
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage('Initialize Dev Environment') {
        when {
            branch 'dev'
          }
        environment {
              TF_VAR_aws_access_key     = credentials('dev-aws-access-key-id')
              TF_VAR_aws_secret_key = credentials('dev-aws-secret-access-key')
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     = credentials('dev-aws-access-key-id')
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials('dev-aws-secret-access-key')
              AWS_REGION = "us-west-2"
          }
        steps {
          sh 'terraform init -backend-config="bucket=${GIT_BRANCH}-terraform-state" -backend-config="dynamodb_table=${GIT_BRANCH}-terraform-state-locking" -backend-config="region=$AWS_REGION" -backend-config="key=${GIT_BRANCH}-terraform-state/terraform.tfstate"'
        }
    }
```

IF i obviously set it before the stage phase in the pipeline of course it works.

```
  agent {
    docker {
      image '/terraform-npm:latest'
      registryCredentialsId 'dockerhubPW'
    }
  }
environment {
        TF_VAR_aws_access_key     = credentials('dev-aws-access-key-id')
        TF_VAR_aws_secret_key = credentials('dev-aws-secret-access-key')
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     = credentials('dev-aws-access-key-id')
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials('dev-aws-secret-access-key')
        AWS_REGION = "us-west-2"
    }
  stages {
    stage('Initialize Dev Environment') {
        when {
            branch 'dev'
          }

        steps {
          sh 'terraform init -backend-config="bucket=${GIT_BRANCH}-terraform-state" -backend-config="dynamodb_table=${GIT_BRANCH}-terraform-state-locking" -backend-config="region=$AWS_REGION" -backend-config="key=${GIT_BRANCH}-terraform-state/terraform.tfstate"'
        }
    }
```

My question is , is there a way to set the environment variables before the stages phase BUT conditionally depending on the branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, there is.

First option: you can run a combination of scripted and declarative pipeline (please note that I haven't checked it works, this is just to send you down a right path):

```
// scripted pipeline
node('master') {
    stage("Init variables") {
        if (env.GIT_BRANCH == 'dev') {
            env.AWS_REGION = "us-west-2"
        }
        else {
        // ...
        }
    }
}

// declarative pipeline
pipeline { 
agent {
    docker {
      image '/terraform-npm:latest'
      registryCredentialsId 'dockerhubPW'
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage('Use variables') {
        steps {
          sh 'echo $AWS_REGION'
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is to use `withEnv` directive inside `steps`:

```
    stage('Initialize Dev Environment') {
        when {
            branch 'dev'
        }
        steps {
            withEnv(['AWS_REGION=us-west-2']) {
                sh 'echo $AWS_REGION'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you MaratC for guiding me in the right path, it def helped. here is what i used

```
      steps {
          withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'qa-aws-access-key-id', variable: 'TF_VAR_aws_access_key'),string(credentialsId: 'qa-aws-secret-access-key', variable: 'TF_VAR_aws_secret_key'),string(credentialsId: 'qa-aws-access-key-id', variable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),string(credentialsId: 'qa-aws-secret-access-key', variable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')]) 
          {
        sh 'terraform plan -var-file=${GIT_BRANCH}.tfvars -out=${GIT_BRANCH}-output.plan'
        }
      }
```